# Laravel Valet and wordpress subfolder installation

Tags: laravel, valet

I want to use a Wordpress in my laravel installation.
For this i put it on /public/blog/*.

The goal is to access WP by  https://mywebsite.test/blog/

The problem is : i can't reach my wordpress installation. 
I'm using Valet on local. How to configure valet to let me access to the subfolder ?
Is it possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mkdir mywebsite
cd mywebsite
valet link
valet secure
mkdir blog
cd blog <== install wordpress here
```

This way it's inside your parked/linked domain.